# Efficient subset of a std::vector<double>

Tags: c++, stdvector

Assume that we have set of double numbers in a `std::vector<double>`. Lets call this one `data`. Now I want to create a new std::vector that is made of an (ordered) subset of `data` via a method `subvector`, e.g. let `data = [0,4,3,5,5,7]` and I want method that gives me

```
std::vector<int> indices(3);
indices[0] = 1;
indices[1] = 2;
indices[2] = 4;
std::vector<double> subdata = data.subvector(indices);
```

and the result should be `subdata = [4,3,5]`. Of course, I can achieve this by simply copying out the values of `data` but what I really want is that if I change values in `subdata`, they also change in `data`, i.e. if I do `subdata[2]=-1` is want that `data = [0,4,3,5,-1,7]`.

So, I have to do thing like "remembering" the pointer of in `data`. I tried several options with putting `&` and `*` here and there but I could not get the desired result.

Answer (score 2):

Storing pointers to the items is a bit dangerous, because a vector's internal buffer can be replaced (automatically) when you append items, and then those pointers would be dangling.

But you can store a pointer or reference to the vector itself, like this:

```
#include <vector>
#include <initializer_list>
using namespace std;

class Subdata
{
    vector<int>&        m_data;
    const vector<int>   m_indices;

public:
    auto operator[]( const int i )
        -> int&
    { return m_data[m_indices[i]]; }

    Subdata( vector<int>&  data, const initializer_list<int>& indices ):
        m_data( data ),
        m_indices( indices.begin(), indices.end() )
    {}
};

#include <iostream>
auto main()
    -> int
{
    vector<int> data = {0, 4, 3, 5, 5, 7};
    Subdata subdata( data, {1, 2, 4} );
    subdata[2] = -1;
    for( const int v : data ) { cout << v << ' '; } cout << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> what I really want is that if I change values in subdata, they also change in data, i.e. if I do `subdata[2]=-1` is want that `data = [0,4,3,5,-1,7]`.

To accomplish that, you need to store *pointers* to the members in `data`. They can be raw pointers (`int*`) or iterators (`std::vector<int>::iterator`).

However, storing pointers is risky. They can be invalidated by modifications to `data`. The safer method would be to just use the indices and get/set the values of the elements of `data` by using the indices.

```
data[indices[0]] = <some value>; // Set the value in data
int x = data[indices[1]];        // Get the value from data
```

Since `std::vector` is a random access container, the cost of accessing the elements of `data` will not impact performance, if that is a concern.